# Adding values from a dataframe to a column in another dataframe pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I add the values from dataframe `A` to a new column (`sum`) in dataframe `B` that contains the given pairs of dataframe `A`? Preferably with a UDF?

output should look like this:

**dataframe A:**

```
|id|value|
|--|-----|
|1 |   10|
|2 |  0.3|
|3 |  100|
```

**dataframe B:**(with added column `sum`)

```
|src|dst|sum  |
|---|---|-----|
|1  |2  |10.3 |
|2  |3  |100.3|
|3  |1  |110  |
```

I've tried this

```python
dfB = dfB.withColumn('sum', sum(dfB.source,dfB.dst,dfA))

def sum(src,dst,dfA):
    return dfA.filter(dfA.id == src).collect()[0][1][0] + dfA.filter(dfA.id == dst).collect()[0][1][0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dfA` is small enough for a broadcast join, then then this should work:

```py
dfB.join(dfA, how="left", on=F.col("src") == F.col("id")).select(
    "src", "dst", F.coalesce(F.col("value"), F.lit(0)).alias("v1")
).join(dfA, how="left", on=F.col("src") == F.col("id")).select(
    "src", "dst", (F.col("v1") + F.coalesce(F.col("value"), F.lit(0))).alias("sum")
)
```

You can remove `.coalesce()`, if the id column contains every src and dst value. There's a few ways to functional this, but your best bet may be using `.transform()`.

```py
def join_sum(join_df):
    def _(df):
        return (
            df.join(join_df, how="left", on=F.col("src") == F.col("id"))
            .select("src", "dst", F.coalesce(F.col("value"), F.lit(0)).alias("v1"))
            .join(join_df, how="left", on=F.col("src") == F.col("id"))
            .select(
                "src",
                "dst",
                (F.col("v1") + F.coalesce(F.col("value"), F.lit(0))).alias("sum"),
            )
        )

    return _


dfB.transform(join_sum(dfA))
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to join the 2 dataframes on condition `(id = src OR id = dst)` then group by to sum the column `value`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

output = df_a.join(
    df_b, 
    (F.col("id") == F.col("src")) | (F.col("id") == F.col("dst"))
).groupBy("src", "dst").agg(F.sum("value").alias("sum"))

output.show()
#+---+---+-----+
#|src|dst|  sum|
#+---+---+-----+
#|  2|  3|100.3|
#|  1|  2| 10.3|
#|  3|  1|110.0|
#+---+---+-----+
```